# CSS Not Clause for media queries - as in a catchall?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a media query, for my CSS, where it displays a block for a certain media type - but I want to display a position:fixed set if CSS rules for all *other* possibilities,

```
header {
    position:fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:960px;
    margin-top: 0px auto 4px auto;
    height: 200px;
}

@media only screen 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
    header {
        position:static;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

So What I'm asking is -- can I set a clause for "all other cases that don't fit this media query, like an else statement, or do I have to set the query in the HTML link reference and then have two separate stylesheets?

If my clauses are not in this query they're in the open and read by all media cases, but I would have to i) put the default actions in a CSS rule inside this query ad ii) then put this media query at the bottom of the CSS page to then "overwrite" the pre-set "fixed" rules.

The rules are not yet written, but I have the header, but I will have about 5 other parts of the site - nav / main / footer which will behave differently, and would like one set for this media query and then another set for the ELSE, clause. Any suggestions?

### Update:

```
@media only not screen(max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)
```

or

```
@media not only screen(max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)
```

Does not work for viewing on laptop in landscape mode... hmm.

Comment: Please check [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#not) logical operator.

Comment: ?? I don't quite get your question. The else clause will be everything that doesn't fit the query. So what is the problem, do you want smaller screens to not have to read rules that don't apply to them.

Comment: thanks @emmanuel that seems to be what I'm looking for, Billy is there an "else" clause in CSS? I can't find one. I want the layout in the media query given to be different from all other layouts, and trying to avoid repeating CSS rules X number of times.

Comment: @billy Because the rules which are not in a media query are executed in every case, which I want them to be executed in every case EXCEPT the case within the media query.

Comment: what about a min-device width 490px; set of rules, that way the smaller screen won't even bother loading them

Comment: @emmanuel sorry but media query not doesn't work. I've edited my question...

Comment: Please try to remove `only` and add an `and`.

Comment: Add an and? I don't understand that part - but will try without the only, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex question, so let's tackle it in **three** parts:

---

### 1.

Straight to the point, consider this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

header {
    /* ideally, red should be here, as default */
    background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
/* the "else" clause you seek: */
@media not screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
</style>
<body>
    <header>
        test header
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally, you'd want "global" default styles to be first, then specifics would override what they need. In ideal world, there would be no need for "else" scenario because that would fall upon that "global".

For example, in the snippet above, `blue` is rendered useless because "else"-style media query with "not" overrides everything what not falls upon yellow.

But I understand, there are different cases and world is not ideal, so let's move on to...

---

### 2.

> can I set a clause for "all other cases that don't fit this media query, like an else statement?

Yes, using `not` like in example above. Guys suggested it already in the comments but your snippet is wrong

`@media only not screen(max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)`

You probably meant:

`@media only not screen and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)`

but that would be wrong as well because CSS spec says:

> [image: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#media-query-modifier]
> https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#media-query-modifier

As you see, it's either `not` or `only` (or nothing), but never both.

Let's assemble from scratch: `type` is `screen`, `condition` is `max-device-width`. We put brackets around condition only:

```css
@media not screen
```

```css
@media not screen and (max-device-width : 480px)
```

```css
@media not screen and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)
```

You can always use [CSSTree validator](https://csstree.github.io/docs/validator.html), it might miss some errors but at least we can make sure our code does not trigger any issues known to its algorithm.

---

### 3.

For posterity, things have changed since 2014 a little spec-wise; now in 2020 the `device-width` (and its counterparts `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`) are [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#device-width). But `orientation` is still cool.